# Remove dynamic ClearCase view from specific Region

Tags: clearcase

Is it possible to remove a dynamic view out of a particular clearcase region?

cleartool -rmview seems to not take a e.g. -region parameter and I was wondering whether there's a more elegant way to achieve this.. or is the only way to change the system's CC settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove a view from a region, that means you don't want to erase it completely, as it still has to work in other regions.

In that case, the right command is:

```
cleartool rmtag -view -tag dynamic-view-tag -region theRightRegion
```

See `rmtag` command:

> The `rmtag` command removes one or more entries from the network's view tag registry or VOB tag registry

A `rmview` would both math a `rmtag`, and un-register the view id (and remove any local trace of the view, like removing the view storage).